# Сохранение файла с заданным именем

Tags: php, javascript, html

На сайте имеется button(Создать страницу) и рядом с ним input:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код имеет вид:

```
 <a  class="sidebar-toggle" >
                       <button style="background:transparent; border: 0; ">Создать страницу:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </button> 
                        <input style="background: #3e95c7;   border: 0; outline:none;" type="text"  value="">
                    </a>
```

По нажатию кнопки, она кстати не заключена в тег `<form>`, у меня сохраняется содержимое   `<div class="getcode">некий текст</div>` на сервере в виде html файла:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Механизм отправки контента в обработчик на JS:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button"); 
button.addEventListener("click", sendSave, false); 

function sendSave() { 
var data = document.querySelectorAll(".getcode"); 


var formData = new FormData(); 



for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) { 
formData.append("data[]", data[i].innerHTML); 
} 

var XHR = "onload" in new XMLHttpRequest() ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest; 
var xhr = new XHR(); 
xhr.open('POST', 'save.php', true); 
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => { 
if (xhr.readyState !== 4) { 
return; 
} 
if (xhr.status === 200) { 
console.log(xhr.responseText); 
} 
}; 
xhr.send(formData);  

}
```

Далее на сервере отлавливаются данные и помещаются в файл следующим php кодом:

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen(date('Ymdhis').'-data.html', 'w'); 
$html = ""; 


foreach($_POST[data] as $data) { 
$html .= $data.PHP_EOL; 
} 

echo (fwrite($fp, $html)) ? "Сохранено" : "Не сохранено"; 

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Имя файла генерируется автоматически, как сделать так чтобы имя файла при сохранении отлавливалось из inputa и по нажатию кнопки передавалось в обработчик и там же прописывалось вместо текущей сгенерированной текущей даты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$fileName = $_POST['input_name'];`

Comment: @rjhdby как это прикрутить к моему коду, ибо решения я уже нахордил но прикручивая они не срабатывали что добавить в JS что в PHP? подскажжите ОТВЕТом пожалуйсста, вроде простая задача но могу осилисть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в input `id="filename"`

```
<input style="..." id="filename" type="text"  value="">
```

Добавить в конец функции `sendSave()`

```
formData.append("filename", document.getElementById("filename").value);
```

В php-скрипте

```
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
```

Comment: а в php куда это вставить?

Comment: Сделал так, в начале php файла вставил строку $filename = $_POST['filename']; И 2 строку модифицировал вот так:  $fp = fopen($filename.'-data.html', 'w');  После этого, сохраяняется файл только 1 раз, с именем [object HTMLInputElement]-data.html, и все и больше сохранений не происходит(не происходят видимо из за функции fopen которая создает файл толька если имени такого не существует, иначе перезаписывает)

Comment: @Павел ой, блин. Сорри, сейчас поправлю :)

Comment: @Павел Обновил ответ. Конечно же надо у `input` забирать его `value`

Comment: Спасибо заработало, отблагодарил повышением реп)